# Last Date and Time in Mondrian MDX

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian

I have a cube amdz with 
measures Amount 
dimension Date/Date
dimension Time/FullTime
dimension Status/Status
dimension customer/customer name
I am using Pentaho/Mondrian.

Would it be possible to get the non empty measures.amount for last Date and last FullTime per status per customer name using Mondrian MDX

Sample data

Customer Name   Status  Date        FullTime Amount

Customer1   Regular 2013-10-27  10:45:05 10.00 
Customer1   Regular 2013-10-27  20:45:05 20.00
Customer1   Special 2013-10-27  24:45:05 30.00
Customer2   Regular 2013-10-27  10:45:05 10.00
Customer2   Regular 2013-10-27  20:45:05 20.00
Customer2   Special 2013-10-27  24:45:05 30.00

Customer1   Regular 2013-10-28  10:45:05 10.00 
Customer1   Regular 2013-10-28  20:45:05 20.00
Customer1   Special 2013-10-28  24:45:05 30.00
Customer2   Regular 2013-10-28  10:45:05 10.00
Customer2   Regular 2013-10-28  20:45:05 20.00
Customer2   Special 2013-10-28  24:45:05 30.00

desired output

Customer1   Regular 2013-10-28  20:45:05 20.00 
Customer1   Special 2013-10-28  24:45:05 30.00
Customer2   Regular 2013-10-28  20:45:05 20.00
Customer2   Special 2013-10-28  24:45:05 30.00

Any help would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks,
Walter

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to implement that from my Analysis Services point of view would be to add a measure of type DateTime to the fact table, and set its aggregation function to `Max`. Then the MDX query would be straightforward, using this measure on the columns, and customer as well as status on the rows. However, I never created a Mondrian cube. Hence I am not sure if this is possible in Mondrian.